# How to properly create dimensions and groups in Crossfilter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crossfilter

I have a data set like so:

```
[
  {
    event: 'open',
    delay: 120,
    createdAt: 157643454332
  },
  {
    event: 'click',
    delay: 240,
    createdAt: 157866452342
  }
  // roughly a 1000 records with data in the above format
]
```

I want to create a crossfilter which looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGzTS.png).

Conditions are as follows:

- If Day of the Week is changed, it changes the other 3 graphs
- If Hour of the Day is changed, it changes the other 3 graphs
- If Opens graph is changed, it changes the Day of Week and Hour of Day but doesn't change Clicks
- If Clicks graph is changed, it changes Day of Week and Hour of Day but doesn't change Opens

I've tried a host of things, and am horribly stuck. Googling hasn't helped either.

Anyone with any pointers which will help me proceed in the right direction, would be helpful!

I have also read the documentation, but it's all terribly confusing.

**Update:** Here is a codesandbox which basically does everything I am doing now to setup crossfilters.

How do I filter it to act like a crossfilter? That is what is confusing me.

https://codesandbox.io/s/l4w2vn5rpz

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle so we can understand what is working and what is not? :)

Comment: @xadhix Have added link to codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I was having trouble understanding.

For anyone landing here in the future, the following snippets I found in a blog post and the API docs will help.

> The function must return naturally-ordered values, i.e., values that
>   behave correctly with respect to JavaScript's `<`, `<=`, `>=` and `>`
>   operators.
>
> In particular, this means that your dimension and group value
>   functions must never return `NaN`, `undefined`, or `null`.

.

> The dimension reads the dataset and groups the item with the same result in the function.

.

> Dimensions allow us to group items in different subsets. Applying a filter is excluding a subset of items from our dataset.

.

> The crossfilter tool used to sort the data is the dimension so the idea is to change the dimension.

The original post can be found [here](https://blog.sicara.com/interactive-dashboard-crossfilter-dcjs-tutorial-7f3a3ea584c2). Also, it is really helpful to thoroughly go through the [API Reference](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) and [Crossfilter Gotchas](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas), after you've gone through the blog post as it helps clarify some things I felt were complicated in the docs.

I hope this helps someone!